# Android Chromecast: Call messageStream.playFrom(position) does not work in MediaProtocolCommand onCompleted

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I had a media player, when user connect to chromecast in the middle of the video, I would like to cast the video to chromecast at the same position in the video where the user left off.

```
mediaProtocolCommand.setListener(new MediaProtocolCommand.Listener() {
     public void onCompleted(MediaProtocolCommand mPCommand) {
          messageStream.playFrom(currentVideoPosition);
     }
});
```

Using the code snippet above I manage to get the video playing but it always start at the beginning of the video

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using the Cast Android sample app. Make sure the parameter value for playFrom is the time in seconds.